# Networking server with multiple clients in java

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I'm implements a fairly simple server that can should handle multiple clients, and I first accepting clients as such

```
    private static Queue<Player> playerList = new ArrayDeque<Player>(); 

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

        // Listen for new clients 
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        int numPlayers = 0;

        while (numPlayers < 2){
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

            if(clientSocket != null){
                // Create a new player 
                Player p = new Player(clientSocket);
                // Add them to the list of players
                playerList.add(p);
            }

        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not listen on port: " + port);
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

From what I have read it seems like there is usually a new thread created for each client, but I don't really see the need to go through this trouble if there is a simpler way. I simply need to be able to send and receive messages between the server and clients.

```
while (true) {
    // Check for anything on the buffer

        // Parse message

}
```

So is there an easy way to just

Listen for incoming messages

Determine which client the message is coming from

Parse the message etc.

All in a loop without creating a separate thread for each client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something like this:

```
while (true) {
    for(Player p : playerList) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getSocket().getInputStream()));
        String data;
        while ((data = reader.readLine() != null) {
            p.packetRecieved(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can work. Concurrent requests will be waiting while the server is processing the current request. But you need to make sure that clients are prepared to process ConnectException and repeat a request. There is a limit for incoming connection queue (50 by default, may be changed). ServerSocket will refuse the connection if the queue is full. See ServerSocket API

BTW if(clientSocket != null) does not make sense, serverSocket.accept() never returns null

Comment: good to know! thanks for the tip. does accept return anything if there is nothing to accept?

Comment: No, it waits until it has something.